# Implementing Mongo Atlas Search on a Document that has dynamic properties

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am having trouble implementing an **Atlas Search** on a document collection where the documents have no fixed field names. All the field names are **highly dynamic**.

**For Example,** A user may create a document with the following fields

```
{
  name: string,
  description: string
}
```

Another user may create a document with the following fields

```
{
  company: string,
  username: string
}
```

This is happening because we provide a feature to users where they can create their own records. So the fields are also dynamic depending on their needs. No, we need to provide **Full-Text Search** Support on these documents but we are struggling to create a **Search Index** because the `path` is **dynamic**.

Is there any way in **Mongo Atlas Search** to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you define the collections [field mapping] you want to define it as `dynamic`:

> You can configure Atlas Search to automatically index all the supported field types in the collection using dynamic mappings.

There are some [limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/define-field-mappings/#limitations) by doing this but it does not sounds like it will affect you.

You then can execute a [wildcard field search](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/path-construction/#wildcard-field-search)

Comment: Thank you. I tried it. But I get `MongoError: index is not allowed in this atlas tier` error. I checked limitations for the `Free Tier`  but found nothing related to `index`. Any idea? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/

Comment: I guess it is as the message says, this is just not a free tier feature. I think your only option is to restructure the data

Comment: Thank you for ur support. Actually, the error was misleading. There are no such limitations, The issue was some `JSON` issue. By the way, `wildcard` won't be helpful in this case because we need to search on a specified field. Anyway, I resolved the issue using `Text` instead of `Autocomplete` with `Dynamic Index` coz the `Autocomplete` not working with `Dynamic Index`.